# Any restrictions on Apple devices that stop connections to local network devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, network, wifi

I'm a developer (I should properly know this) but are there any settings/restriction features across Apple Products (iOS, macOS, iPadOS etc.) that disallows connections to local networked devices?

I cannot, for some reason, connect to my Philips Hue Bridge via it's local IP address, nor can the app connect to it. I also cannot connect to most other local networked devices on any of my Apple products for some reason? I head over to my Windows PC (using ethernet) and it works, I use my other family member's iPhone/devices and theirs works too!

So my only assumption is that its some sort of setting/feature across iCloud preferences that stops me from accessing said devices?

P.S, yes I have allowed local network access for the Hue app...

UPDATE:

HomeKit devices locally are not working either but are working on my family members devices

Comment: There's no restrictions.  Do you have an app or profile or DNS entry that could be blocking the communication?

Comment: @fsb nope, nothing. I cant even connect to my Pi-hole server as its local ip ahaha. If I go onto my mobile data on my iPhone and connect to my home network via VPN then I can easily go on the devices mentioned above? What gives im so stumbled....

Comment: When you say you allowed local network for Hue, did you do that in the Privacy -> Local Network setting?

Comment: @fsb Yes, but thats only for the app, I cannot connect via local IP from safari either...

Comment: Wow, I'm stumpted, too.  The only thing I can think of is Hue might use a webview and there's a content blocker stopping it.  Maybe a Reset Network Settings will fix it?

Comment: @fsb I can't connect to my web apps locally on my server either so I doubt thats the case either. (My families devices can connect to all of this and I can get to my webapps via my public domain too on the same device...)?

Comment: if you're on wifi, some routers separate the 2.4GHz and 5GHz band networks to prevent local network traffic across bands

Comment: @wrossmck nice idea but I've joined both bands together for simplistic sake